# Magento Category not displaying on home page

Tags: javascript, magento, categories

Had to change "Cameras" to "Digital Cameras", copied the exact same settings as i had in the "Cameras" in the category attributes and now on my homepage the first category towards the middle of the page will not display, so i put everything back to the way it was and still won't show

link:
http://47stphoto.simple-helix.net/index.php

yet all the others with the same settings still do?

Comment: Can't seem to get to the site...is it still up?

Comment: yes we are having some speed issues at the moment but it is still up

Answer (score 2):

- Check the status(Include in Navigation Menu) of the new category is set to yes.
- Check Include in Navigation Menu is set to yes?

Comment: both are set to yes, still doesn't appear there

Comment: Which version of Magento you are using?